# How to make an array grid, width the width and height given in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am stuck on an excersice I have from school. We have to create a function that creates a grid, given the height and width and fill up everything with a value that is given. I almost have the solution, but there is still one test case that gives an error and I can't seem to understand why. [Here are the test cases.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnVtj.png)

```
function createGrid(width, height, value) {
    var x = new Array(width);
    for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        x[i] = new Array(height);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            x[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Made a spelling error in the question, width should be with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are making a mistake in printing the data. You can't print them in the same loop in which you are inserting the values. you have to run a different loop.

I have printed them as table in the snippet. By clicking on the button it will print (4,7,0). you can check other values by changing the html for the button.

```js
function createGrid(width, height, value) {
  var x = new Array(width);
  for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      x[i] = new Array(height);
  }
  for (var k = 0; k < width; k++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      x[k][j] = value;
    }
  }
  //printing the data
  var innerTable = " ";
  for (k=0;k<height;k++){
    innerTable += "<tr>";
    for (j = 0; j < width; j++){
      innerTable += "<td>"+x[j][k]+"</td>";
    }
    innerTable += "</tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("toPrint").innerHTML = innerTable;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createGrid(4,7,0)">ClickMe</button>
<table id="toPrint">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your variables for consistency. Try using 'h' and 'w' instead of 'i' and 'j', and I think you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In third loop, you misplaced indexes. Instead of x[i][j], there should be x[j][i].

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve it? I get 0|0 in the second test case.